# How do I plot power spectral diagram in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, fft

I have this function in python:

```py
omega = (
    5.4547990171221e-20 * np.sin(4.35893728452007e-5 * t) ** 2
    - 6.80677962622999e-40 * np.sin(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)
                           * np.cos(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)
    + 3.84259827520928e-19 * np.sin(2831.25294891184 * t) ** 2
    - 2.77555756156289e-17 * np.sin(2831.25294891184 * t)
                           * np.cos(2831.25294891184 * t)
    + 5.45479901712209e-20 * np.cos(4.35893728452007e-5 * t) ** 2
    - 3.87725551857472e-22 * np.cos(2831.25294891184 * t) ** 2
    + 1391.74933087011 * np.exp(-40.0880015429485 * t)
                       * np.sin(2831.25294891184 * t)
    + 9.5003864918335e-13 * np.exp(-40.0880015429485 * t)
                          * np.cos(2831.25294891184 * t)
    - 0.000158807497479067 * np.exp(-9.500167e-15 * t)
                           * np.sin(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)
    + 2094.39510239319 * np.exp(-9.500167e-15 * t)
    * np.cos(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)
)
```

When plotted, it looks like the left image on the figure:

[image: img1]

I need to somehow get the graph on the right side. It is probably a power spectral diagram, if I'm right. It has something to do with fast Fourier transform, but I'm not exactly sure how to plot it, because everything on the web gives different results, unfortunately different from the desired graph too.

I've tried numpy's fft and later on more sophisticated scipy's welch:

```py
freqs, psd = sig.welch(signal, 10000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.semilogx(
    freqs, np.log10(np.abs(psd))
)
```

However, I still can't achieve this:

[image: img2]

Comment: Have you tried `loglog` instead of `semilog`?

Comment: Modulo scale, that looks exactly like what you have sketched.  To what part do you object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard spectral diagram looks much like your last plot, though your function produces much more than 10**-4 in the pass band:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def a(t: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return (
        5.4547990171221e-20 * np.sin(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)**2 
        - 6.80677962622999e-40 * np.sin(4.35893728452007e-5 * t) * np.cos(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)
        + 3.84259827520928e-19 * np.sin(2831.25294891184 * t)**2
        - 2.77555756156289e-17 * np.sin(2831.25294891184 * t) * np.cos(2831.25294891184 * t)
        + 5.45479901712209e-20 * np.cos(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)**2
        - 3.87725551857472e-22 * np.cos(2831.25294891184 * t)**2
        + 1391.74933087011 * np.exp(-40.0880015429485 * t) * np.sin(2831.25294891184 * t)
        + 9.5003864918335e-13 * np.exp(-40.0880015429485 * t) * np.cos(2831.25294891184 * t)
        - 0.000158807497479067 * np.exp(-9.500167e-15 * t) * np.sin(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)
        + 2094.39510239319 * np.exp(-9.500167e-15 * t) * np.cos(4.35893728452007e-5 * t)
    )


fsample = 1e5
tsample = 1/fsample
t = np.arange(0, 1, tsample)
a_t = a(t)
a_f = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(a_t))
f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=t.size, d=tsample)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(f, a_f)
plt.show()
```

[image: spectrum]